# Node Express gives two responses, breaks front-end script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Due to something in my Express routing, the data seems to be sent twice to the Angular front-end. This seems to send Mixpanel into an endless loop that causes parts of the app not to load properly.

The reason for the following code is I want to detect certain user agents and send them something other than what the regular user sees. This is because certain user agents won't load Javascript, but I need them to scrape some information from the page.

From my **server.js**:

```
app = express();

app 
    .use( morgan( 'dev' ) )
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { limit: '50mb', extended: true } ) )
    .use( bodyParser.json( { limit: '50mb' } ) )
    .use( '/api', require('./routes/usersRoute.js') )
    .use( express.static( indexPath ) )
    .all( '/*', require( './routes/home.js' ) )
```

From my **home.js**:

```
router.get( '/:user/:stream/:slug', function( req, res, next ) {

    if ( req.headers['user-agent'].indexOf( 'facebook' ) != -1 ) {
                    if ( !req.params.user && !req.params.stream && !req.params.slug ) return next()

        contentController.findUserId( req.params.user )
        .then( function ( userId ) {
            if ( !userId ) return next()

            contentController.projectContent( req.params.slug )
            .then( function ( item ) {
                if ( !item ) return next()

                createOpenGraph( item[0] )
                .then( function ( OG ) {
                    return res.status( 200 ).send( OG )
                })
                .catch( function ( error ) {
                    console.log( error )
                    return res.status( 500 ).json( error )
                })
            })
        })
    } else { 
        return res.status( 200 )
            .set( { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' } )
            .sendFile( indexPath )
    }
})

router.get( '/*', function( req, res ) {
    return res.status( 200 )
        .set( { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' } )
        .sendFile( indexPath )
})
```

A few pages seem broken, and I'm not sure why some pages break but not others. Notably, the page I am trying to detect in the `.get( '/:user/:stream/:slug'...)` function in `home.js` breaks. On that page, in the console, I can see an error that angular was loaded twice, which corroborates that Mixpanel is breaking due to a double response problem. This error doesn't appear on pages that don't break. Further more, I can see that both functions (in the `home.js`) are being called each time I do a load on a broken page, but not the working ones.

I'm open to all advice on how to do this better.

Comment: Perhaps show some code in the "do the facebook stuff" section.

Comment: @ralh I've added it. I didn't think the problem came from there but on second look maybe it does.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the routes on the `routes/home.js` file to be call before any other matching route. So you need to pass the control to the next route executing the next parameter.
Probably you want to send the file on another route, perhaps on `.use( '/app', require('./routes/appRoutes.js') )` or on the last method as on the example.

```
router.get( '/:user/:stream/:slug', function( req, res, next ) {

  if ( req.headers['user-agent'].indexOf( 'facebook' ) != -1 ) {
    /*Do the facebook stuff*/
  } else { 
     res.status( 200 );
  }
  next();
 });
```

// routes/appRoutes.js

```
    router.get( '/*', function( req, res, next ) {
        return res.status( 200 )
        /*Set you headers independently on the api routes as you might prefer to set the content type to application/json*/
         .set( { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' } )
         .sendFile(indexPath ).end();
    });
```

// server.js

```
app = express();

app.use( morgan( 'dev' ) )
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { limit: '50mb', extended: true } ) )
    .use( bodyParser.json( { limit: '50mb' } ) )
    .use( '/api', require('./routes/usersRoute.js') )
    .use( '/app', require('./routes/appRoutes.js') )
    .use( express.static( indexPath ) )
    .all( '/*', require( './routes/home.js' ) );
```

Comment: Interesting, in some cases this does fix the problem, but on other pages it says Cannot read property 'end' of undefined, and if I put it on both then no pages work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the url that are not working?

Comment: Working: `/app/discover/watch`, not working: `/alpha/watch/558b7c5d59f5c2a6bed63555`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize of the `app.all` call. Instead of ending the request as both routes are intended to be middleware functions call `next()` at the end.of each function and send the file on the last method.

Comment: The `/app` part is a route made by Angular. Will I also have to d this with every route made in Angular? Actually `/app` is also a folder in my `/public` directory. And what about `/js`, `/images` and all the other folders I have?

Comment: I think that you are using a seed for your application, because angular it self doesn't create any routes. From your code I understand that there is an api part and an web part that returns the file, I don't know if is the same file or not. I separate it on another router so that the middleware functions don't return the file and you can call next on them. For static content you could create a route that match for anything that has one of those extensions and just return that file

Comment: Angular does make routes, either with ngRoute or the popular ui-router, which I'm using. What do you mean by seed?

Comment: Angular has a module to create but you define them. There is projects in github that contain some configuration to make you start quickly as ngSeed. Anyway the front end routes and the back end routes doesn't conflicts. I would suggest to separate the routes for the api and the routes for the app